# Getting an error whilst adding items to an arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am getting an error when I try to add items to an arraylist, I am not sure what I have done wrong.

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
buttonList.add(button);
buttonList.add(button1);
buttonList.add(button2);
```

The error I am getting are:

```
Syntax error on token "button", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
Syntax error on token "button1", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
Syntax error on token "button2", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
```

full code;

```
public buttons {
    JButton button = new JButton(); 
    JButton button1 = new JButton();
    JButton button2 = new JButton();

    ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    buttonList.add(button);
    buttonList.add(button1);
    buttonList.add(button2);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `button` `button1` and `button2` ?

Comment: Please show your whole code. Looks like `ArrayList<JButton> buttonList` is a field of your class and you're not initializing it inside the class constructor.

Comment: Is `buttons` supposed to be a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot add Java code directly in the class definition, instead add it in a method.

Move this part of the code:

```
buttonList.add(button);
buttonList.add(button1);    
buttonList.add(button2);
```

Into a class constructor:

```
public buttons() {
    buttonList.add(button);
    buttonList.add(button1);    
    buttonList.add(button2);
}
```

Also, it would be better if you initialize these variables in the class constructor as well:

```
public buttons {

    JButton button; 
    JButton button1 = new JButton();
    JButton button2 = new JButton();

    ArrayList<JButton> buttonList;

    public buttons() {
        button = new JButton();
        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();
        buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        //...
        buttonList.add(button);
        buttonList.add(button1);
        buttonList.add(button2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use the variables in my other methods in the same class, that why I made them global.

Comment: @user3288493 the problem is not about making the variables *global*, the problem is how you use them. If you notice, my answer keeps the variables as fields in your class, just moves the initialization to the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

put inside the main method

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    JButton button = new JButton(); 
    JButton button1 = new JButton();
    JButton button2 = new JButton();

     ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        buttonList.add(button);
        buttonList.add(button1);
        buttonList.add(button2);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use an ***instance initializer*** as in this code (notice the opening and closing braces arround the buttonList.add() statements):

```
public class Button {
  JButton button = new JButton();
  JButton button1 = new JButton();
  JButton button2 = new JButton();
  ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

  {
    buttonList.add(button);
    buttonList.add(button1);
    buttonList.add(button2);
  }

  // rest of the code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables:
 button, button1 or button2
do not exist

try

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
JButton button = new JButton();
buttonList.add(button);
JButton button1 = new JButton();
buttonList.add(button1);
JButton button2 = new JButton();
buttonList.add(button2);
```